# Beautify plugin for CodeBlocks IDE

Tags: codeblocks

Like Atom, Sublime and VS Code, is there a beautify plugin for CodeBlocks IDE?

I tried the default AStyle plugin in CodeBlocks, but nothing fancy happened to my code.
I had selected all the code before doing this (Ctrl+A)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_Plugins) you can find a list of CodeBlocks plugins. There does not seems to be a Beautifier plugin.
If by Beautifier you mean a plugin that gives a modern look to the GUI, I don't think you can find him anytime soon.
CodeBlocks is built on wxWidgets libraries that currently don't allow the use of themes (as dark mode).

Comment: thanks! By beautifier I meant a plugin which beautify our codes like adding spaces between variables, adding proper tabs, basically make our code look better. There's this feature in OnlineGDB compiler also!